# why evil regular expression will cause ReDoS?

Tags: regex

Currently I am looking into ReDoS: Regular express denial of Service

some bad(evil) regular expression will cause low performance of validation

but why.... I search for wiki and owasp, the answer is mainly for NFA DFA that I could hardly understand....

Could anyone help me with some good sample of explaination....?

Comment: Do you understand what a NFA is and how it works?

Comment: @Bergi no I don't understand the NFA

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nondeterministic_finite_automaton

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's called [*Catastrophic Backtracking*](https://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html).

It occurs when there's no match, but there are O(2<sup>n</sup>) ways to not match that must all be explored before returning `false`.

The example in the linked article from https://www.regular-expressions.info is `(x+x+)+y`, which when used with input of `xxxxxxxxxx` will take about 2500 steps to discover there's no match. Add one `x` and it takes 5000 steps, and so on. With input of 100 `x`s, you're talking billions of years of computing time.

The reason is there are `m` ways that `x+x+` can match `m` `x`s and there are `n / m` ways that `(x+x+)` can be repeated over `n` `x`s and `m` can be an arbitrary number less than `n`. The exploration tree is like a binary tree of ways of carving up the input, leading to the time complexity of O(2<sup>n</sup>).